# sql get results from one column with the name of another column

Tags: sql

Sorry for the title I'm not sure how to word my question.

I have 3 tables `Info`, `Description`, `Encounter`.

**Info**:

```
Patient_NO   ENCOUNTER_NO   Problem_1
1                1             V707
1                2             V343
2                3             P567
```

**Description**:

```
Problem_Description   Problem_Code
Cold                     V707
Knee Pain                V343
Headache                 P567
```

**Encounter**:

```
Patient_NO ENCOUNTER_NO
1               1
1               2
2               3
```

How this works is someone creates an encounter and they enter a problem then it gets saved to the patient. a patient can have multiply encounters.

I'm trying to select Problem_1 and then join it on problem code, but I want it to display the problem description and not the actual code itself. But I only want it to display the problem that was entered in that specific encounter.

If this makes sense to anyone or I can try explaining better.

Comment: Yes you are right it makes no sense. Show us your backend program. probably might make some sense

Comment: It makes sense to me and what you are attempting is very fundamental.  Given your difficulties in even attempting this, I have heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: What is the table `Encounter` for? It contains no information that is not already present in table `Info` it seems. Better drop the table `Encounter` in order to avoid redundancy.

Comment: With SQL questions always tag your DBMS (e.g. SQL Server or Oracle or MySQL). Moreover it is good that you show sample data, but you should also show the expected output, so we see how many columns, how many rows, and which values, in order to get a better picture. And then it is usually expected that you show what you tried and tell us where you got stuck. You already say that you join on problem code, which is exactly what you should do. So where is your problem; what is your query so far?

Comment: `Problem_1` is a strange name for a column. Why is this not `Problem_Code` as in the other table?

Comment: @Thorsten There is a `Problem_2`, `Problem_3`, `Problem_4` columns also, i just simplified my problem down to focus on the parts needed. The question is poorly constructed, without all the info, but if i gave you all the info, i imagine people would get hung up on a lot of un-needed parts. Sorry still kinda new to using stackoverflow D:. Conversation with Shnugo below his answer did give me the idea to just change the data expressions though and that ended up working. Thanks for advice on tagging though.

Comment: To tell the truth: I guessed there was `Problem_2` and maybe more. But why are there exactly 4 problems? What makes `Problem_1` #1 and `Problem_2` #2? What would you do if `Problem_1` to `Problem_3` where NULL, and only `Problem_4` were used? Etc. Usually you'd not have several *columns* for different problems, but several *rows*. That makes querying the data much easier.

Comment: When a patient comes in, say they have a headache and sore feet, the doctor would then put headache into problem_1 and sorefeet into problem_2 and so on. This would all get saved into one row. I didnt make the tables or columns. I'm not sure why they chose to set it up this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in SQL Server, other RDBMS should be similar...

```
DECLARE @Info TABLE(Patient_NO INT,ENCOUNTER_NO INT,Problem_1 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Info VALUES
 (1,1,'V707')
,(1,2,'V343')
,(2,3,'P567');

DECLARE @Description TABLE(Problem_Description VARCHAR(100),Problem_Code VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Description VALUES 
 ('Cold','V707')
,('Knee Pain','V343')
,('Headache','P567');

DECLARE @Encounter TABLE(Patient_NO INT, ENCOUNTER_NO INT);
INSERT INTO @Encounter VALUES
 (1,1)
,(1,2)
,(2,3);

SELECT e.ENCOUNTER_NO 
      ,i.Patient_NO 
      ,i.Problem_1
      ,d.Problem_Description 
FROM @Encounter AS e
INNER JOIN @Info AS i ON e.Patient_NO=i.Patient_NO AND e.ENCOUNTER_NO=i.ENCOUNTER_NO
INNER JOIN @Description AS d ON i.Problem_1 = d.Problem_Code
```

The result:

```
1   1   V707    Cold
2   1   V343    Knee Pain
3   2   P567    Headache
```

Comment: This won't work unfortunately, the result needs to be, where its returning i.Problem_1 instead of V707 it should display Cold

Comment: @mol, ???? If you look at the bottom of my answer you find besides the Code "V707" the word "Cold", and besides "V343" youd find "Knee Pain"... What else do you need?

Comment: The program i have to use, can only display 1 result/column not 4

Comment: @mol, really, buy yourself a beginners book... Just change the SELECT in the way, that you return the columns you need only... Easiest was to set a double minus befode the ",i.Problem_1"